# Remote Desktop and Plesk passwords are lost

Tags: php, plesk

I am in big trouble. Remote desktop and Plesk passwords are mismatched , I am not able to connect to remote server. I have two login options from Plesk. One as admin which is not working. The second is the user account.
I uploaded PHP file by running from url maybe can recover the admin password.
command format from CMD   "%plesk_bin%\plesksrvclient" -set newpassword

```
  <?php
$output = shell_exec("\'%plesk_bin %\plesksrvclient\\' -set earth2000");
echo "<pre> Output: ".$output."</pre>";
echo "<pre><br>OK</pre>"
?>
```

Password recovery from login page  gives email address not registered. 
The idea is to execute cmd line commands in order to fix the problem.
Is not works. Is there other way or any better idea to reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reset admin's password by simple php script. In this case Plesk would have been known as the most vulnerable product :)
You should use system (Windows) accounts for RDP access, but not Plesk accounts.